# What is the problem in my timeout implementation?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, timer, timeout

I'm trying to use a DHT22 (temperature and humidity sensor). Here is its datasheet:
[DHT22 Datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Temperature/DHT22.pdf)

In first few seconds, I can get values. But after a while it gets stuck in here:

[image: it stucks in here]

So I tried to implement a timeout to prevent this. I start another timer (TIM14,) and after 2 seconds I try pull the pin to low manually.

But as a result, variable 'i' (which is in the HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback function) never increments. So, again the code gets stuck in same line.

How can I implement a timeout to pull the pin low after a while?

EDIT: I learned that​ callbacks are operating in interrupt context. So I should change my alghoritm - but how can I do this without using another timer?

```
 /* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim3;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim14;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint8_t Rh_byte1, Rh_byte2, Temp_byte1, Temp_byte2;
uint16_t sum, RH, TEMP;
uint8_t check = 0;
uint8_t volatile k=0;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM14_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void set_gpio_output (void);
void set_gpio_input (void);
void delay_us(uint32_t);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */


void DHT22_start (void)
{
    set_gpio_output ();  // set the pin as output
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, 0);   // pull the pin low
    delay_us(500);   // wait for 500us
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, 1);   // pull the pin high
    delay_us(30);   // wait for 30us
    set_gpio_input ();   // set as input
}

void check_response (void)
{
     delay_us(40);
    if (!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2)))
    {
        delay_us (80);
        if ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2))) check = 1;
    }
    while ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2)));   // wait for the pin to go low
}

uint8_t read_data (void)
{
    uint8_t i,j;
    for (j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        while (!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2)));   // wait for the pin to go high
        delay_us(40);   // wait for 40 us
        if ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2)) == 0)   // if the pin is low
        {
            i&= ~(1<<(7-j));   // write 0
        }
        else i|= (1<<(7-j));  // if the pin is high, write 1
        HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim14); //start timer
        while ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2))); //IT STUCKS HERE
        HAL_TIM_Base_Stop(&htim14); //stop timer

    }
    return i;
}

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

/*Configure GPIO pin : PA1 */
void set_gpio_input (void)
 {
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
 }

 /*Configure GPIO pin : PA2 */
 void set_gpio_output (void)
 {
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
 }

 void delay_ticks(uint32_t ticks)
 { //SYSTICK TIMER 24 BIT
     SysTick->LOAD = ticks;
     SysTick->VAL = 0;
     SysTick->CTRL = SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;
     SysTick->CTRL &= ~SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK_DIV8;
     SysTick->CTRL |= SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK;
     // COUNTFLAG is a bit that is set to 1 when counter reaches 0.
     // It's automatically cleared when read.

     while ((SysTick->CTRL & SysTick_CTRL_COUNTFLAG_Msk) == 0);
     SysTick->CTRL = 0;

 }

 void delay_us(uint32_t us)
 {
     delay_ticks(us * 8); //8 e boldun
 }

 static inline void delay_ms(uint32_t ms)
  {
      delay_ticks(ms * 8000); //8 e boldun
  }

 void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
 {
    if(htim->Instance == TIM3)
    {

        DHT22_start ();
        check_response ();
        Rh_byte1 = read_data ();
        Rh_byte2 = read_data ();
        Temp_byte1 = read_data ();
        Temp_byte2 = read_data ();
        sum = read_data();

        TEMP = ((Temp_byte1<<8)|Temp_byte2);
        RH = ((Rh_byte1<<8)|Rh_byte2);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_4);
    }

    if(htim->Instance == TIM14)
    {
        k++; //increment i in every 500 ms
        if(k==4) //if it reaches two seconds pull the pin to low
        {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        i=0;
        }

 }
 }

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_TIM14_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim3);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief TIM3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 1 */
  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 7999;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_DOWN;
  htim3.Init.Period = 3999;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM14 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM14_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM14_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM14_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM14_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM14_Init 1 */
  htim14.Instance = TIM14;
  htim14.Init.Prescaler = 7999;
  htim14.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim14.Init.Period = 499;
  htim14.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim14.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim14) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }    
}
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{ 
  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
}
```

Comment: You should declare `i` as `volatile`.

Comment: thank you, i did but still it doesn't increment ever

Comment: Why does it get stuck?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not understand.

Answer (score 1):

I added these two lines and now it works.

```
uint32_t first_val = TIM3->CNT; 
while ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2 && (( TIM3->CNT - first_val) < 8000)  )));//continue after 1ms
```